# substr() return incorrect number of characters

Tags: php, substring, substr

`substr()` is returning 28 characters instead of 25.

`$nature_goods` is the input field, where user can enter string containing special characters.

**Code**

```
$nature_goods =  "Nature quantityyy of goods is nice 120pcs 1*X23X24898";
echo strlen($nature_goods);
echo "<br>";
echo substr($nature_goods, 0,25);
echo "<br>";
echo strlen(substr($nature_goods, 0,25));
echo "<br>";
echo substr($nature_goods, 25,50);
echo "<br>";
echo strlen(substr($nature_goods, 25,50));
echo "<br>";
```

**Output**

```
53
Nature quantityyy of good
25
s is nice 120pcs 1*X23X24898
28
```

I tried `mb_substr()` and also `mb_strlen()`, but I do not see any multibyte string creating a problem. Can someone point out the mistake?

Comment: no mistake - your output is correct. there are only 28 chars starting from `s is.....` so `substr($nature_goods, 25,50);` will return only 28

Comment: But substr(25,50) must return 25 characters right?

Comment: no, it will return max 50 chars from 25th position check [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) if you want only 25 chars you should use `substr($nature_goods, 25,25);`

Comment: Oh yes thanks :) How can I close the question?

Comment: I think just delete the question. not of much use for future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using substr incorrectly.

You are using the last value passed to the function as an end point rather than a length, as in grab the characters between 25 and 50, instead of using substr as it supposed to be used, which, as you have written it, is grab 50 characters after skipping the first 25 characters.

The final function call should be substr($nature_goods, 25, 25); if you are expecting to receive 25 characters in return.

Values expected for substr:

substr ( string $string , int $start , int $length )

Full documentation here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

In substr() function third parameter is used to set the length not to set the position. For more details please visit

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php